# How do i remove white border from my code for website?

Tags: html, css

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guosgm9f/)

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
    #background {
        height: 100%;
        background: url(http://phosproject.com/wp-content/themes/phos_theme/images/7.jpg); no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 440px;
    height: 460px;
    margin-top: -230px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -220px; /* Half the width */

}
```

On my website the background seems to have a white border around it and makes it look bad and i was wondering how i could remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html `body` has a default margin. You need to remove it.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/guosgm9f/1/)